# Angular 2 material datepicker ngModel not displaying value

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to angular and material 2, I am using material date picker in my form to display and select the date. I am able to select the date and bind to ngModel. But when I try to bind my response to ngModel showing nothing. I have converted my string date to date and then binding to ngModel. Below is the code, Please help me where i am missing.

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" [matDatepicker]="dateOfBirth" 
          class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customer.dateOfBirth"
            placeholder="Date of birth" required>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateOfBirth"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #dateOfBirth></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error>Date of birth is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

my ts file getting the response from json

```
   customer: CustomerModel = new CustomerModel();
 this.customerService.getResponse().subscribe(resp => {
           this.customer= resp;
 console.log('Date:'+this.customer.dateOfBirth);// able to print
        });

    Class CustomerModel {
        dateOfBirth: Date; 
         //other customer details
      }
```

Here I have created sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvqugs

Comment: Do you see an error message in the console?

Comment: can you try to provide your code on stackblitz?

Comment: @ConnorsFan: No, I didn't see any error

Comment: @davecar21: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvqugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it, I was converting the string date format and then tried to bind with the ngModel. I removed my format date part(using DatePipe) and converted string to date.

```
    if (date) {
  let dateOld: Date = new Date(date);
  return dateOld;
    }
```

Here the updated code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvqugs

Answer (score 1):

On your example from stackblitz, on init, you set the date to a string value, that is not accepted by datepicker component. If you comment ngOnInit method, it will display the value.

Not enough details in the code here to know what type is customer.dateOfBirth. It works fine with type date.

This example from the documentation shows different ways of binding the component, even with a serialized value: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlerqrdamjl?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html

Comment: my json response is sending string date, I have converted string to date, But still not working